# How to make a subpage unavailable for navigating...?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've got the following structure:

- pages/blog/[...slug].jsx
- pages/blog/Create.jsx

The main problem is, I've got no idea how to make the "create" file unavailable for a browser navigation.

I need to open this "Create" page (Component) in my slug file. I know, I can create another directory and add files like that over there, but I don't find a such type of approach convenient.

Can I do something like this in the nextjs context?

Comment: I'd recommend not putting `create.jsx` under the `pages` folder if it's not meant to be a page. Move it to your `components` folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make a seperate folder other than pages ,like example components folder

-pages
->blog
->[slug].jsx

-components
->Create.jsx

Now u can import Create.jsx in your [slug].jsx file.